# Why buttons listeners does not work for mobile in exjts

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I'm trying to add a doubleTap/tap/click listener in a button when the application is in a mobile device to fire an event or throw any event but any option is working.

I have this fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3lab
Extjs Version: 7.5.1
Theme: Triton
Toolkit: modern

I forgot to mention, is this change related with acessibility so need to turn on talkback, voiceOver on phone settings. Also it works for IOS ( SE and Iphone 8 tested ), but does not work for Android device.
Any help with that?

Thanks

Comment: The fiddle is using triton classic toolkit.  Classic is not designed to work on tablets/phones if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @mcg1103 You are right, I changed for using the modern toolkit. Now it's correct.